# Python is running a script randomly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've run into an interesting problem. When I run python on command-line and try to import 'requests', I'm seeing the following error.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2013, 21:33:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Difference is 23 hours and 15 minutes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 9, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
    _startTime = time.time()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'time'
>>>
```

I had this script called time.py in the same directory as the one I'm running python from. That script has been long deleted. But I still see the output of that script "Difference is 23 hours and 15 minutes." when I try to import the module. But if I change directories and try importing the module, it works just fine. I just thought this was weird. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must still have the `time.pyc` file containing the bytecode that was generated the last time that the (now missing) `time.py` was compiled.

When you import a module, Python looks to see if there's an existing `.pyc`file for that module, and if its date is more recent than the corresponding `.py` file, it loads the bytecode contained in that file.

Delete that, and things should work as you expect.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files) in the python docs for more information.

Comment: That worked. However, why does python load the bytecode of a .pyc which is not related to the module I'm importing?

Comment: Requests imports `time`, and when you execute that code in the directory containing the leftover `time.pyc`, it uses that instead of correctly importing the `time` module that's in the standard library.